# Select all categories with COUNT of sub-categories

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select all categories with count of its sub-categories.

Assume here are my tables:

**categories**

```
id | title
----------
1  | colors
2  | animals
3  | plants
```

**sub_categories**

```
id | category_id | title | confirmed
------------------------------------
1        1          red       1
2        1          blue      1
3        1          pink      1
4        2          cat       1
5        2          tiger     0
6        2          lion      0
```

What I want is :

```
id |  title  | count
------------------
1    colors     3
2    animals    1
3    plants     0
```

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, count(s.category_id) as count from categories c
LEFT JOIN sub_categories s on c.id = s.category_id
WHERE c.confirmed = 't' AND s.confirmed='t'
GROUP BY c.id, c.title
ORDER BY count DESC
```

The only problem with this query is that this query does not show categories with 0 sub categories!

You also can check that on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83add/1)

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: move the `where` conditions to `left join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you don't get rows with zero counts is that `WHERE` clause checks `s.confirmed` to be `t`, thus eliminating rows with `NULL`s from the outer join result.

Move `s.confirmed` check into join expression to fix this problem:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, count(s.category_id) as count from categories c
LEFT JOIN sub_categories s on c.id = s.category_id AND s.confirmed='t'
WHERE c.confirmed = 't' 
GROUP BY c.id, c.title
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Adding Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83add/13

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this too (it evidence what column(s) you are really grouping by):

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, RC
from categories c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_id, COUNT(*) AS RC 
           FROM sub_categories 
           WHERE confirmed= 't' 
           GROUP BY category_id) s on c.id = s.category_id
WHERE c.confirmed = 't' 
ORDER BY RC DESC
```